# List<String> in Processing

Tags: java, list

I am trying to implement the java based NLP „RFTagger“ to a Processing Sketch in order to analyze Tweets.

- Using Twitter4j as described here http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/updated-quick-tutorial-processing-twitter
- Using RFTagger to analyze Tweets: http://sifnos.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/resource/A4/rftj/

After I filtered out all retweets, hashtags and profile names in order to have clear sentences to work with, the words of one sentence are stored in an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> sentsTweet = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now I’d like to have the sentence analyzed by RFTagger. I just implemented the library as described on the RFTagger Website:

```
List <String> tags = rft.getTags(sentsTweet);
```

Unfortunately within Processing the class "List" is unknown / not available (?) / Error Message: *Cannot find a class or type named “List“*

I know I could transform the data into some other, manageable format. Like this:

```
Object[] tags = (rft.getTags(sentsTweet)).toArray();
```

But I need to store the data how it is in order to send it a second time to RFTagger to use it's tagset converter:

```
TagsetConverter conv = ConverterFactory.getConverter("stts");
List<String> sttsTags = new LinkedList<String>();
for ( String tag : tags ) {
    sttsTags.add(conv.rftag2tag(tag));
}
```

Now as *`List<String>`* doesn't work in Processing do you guys have an idea how I could handle the data and or communication of RFTagger it?

Kind regards,
Marv

Comment: Have you imported the `List` type inside your class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This has nothing to do with the processing library.**

`RFTagger.getTags()` returns `java.util.List` which is part of the JDK and JRE. You need to add the import for the `List` class:

```
import java.util.List;
```